# CSS Float left, right, left, right... and all to the top

Tags: css, css-float

Horrible title of this question, I know. Sorry.

I have four divs [similar to this](http://jsfiddle.net/eZGTm/) . What i want to do is simply to make the vertical space between div number 2 and 4 to be removed, and without changing the structure of the HTML. Is it possible to do with just CSS (of course without negative margins or other non generic solutions)? And I also want the div 1 and 3 to be without the vertical space in the case of a longer div 2 than 1.

The desired result would graphicly look [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/smgdm/).

Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible, and you would certainly have to specify your desired layout *much* better to get any meaningful suggestions. For example, it is by accident that there are only two columns in the example or is it part of your layout?

Comment: This is how floats work. You probably need a JavaScript solution such as [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Can also be done using CSS3 columns module but the ordering would change.

Comment: @Jon, i will work on that but seems like people understood what i asked for.

Comment: @marreone: Excuse me, but people gave you Javascript solutions (aircraft carriers) when you asked for an improvised weapon ("just CSS"). They did not *have* to understand, because Javascript can do anything.

Comment: @apnerve, yes I also thought of that. However this will be the main layout of a site and therefor not a possible solution for me since the support for columns are not that great at the moment. But nice input, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not with just floats. That would be to use absolute positioning, or change the structure of the html so you have div number #2 and #3 hare right floated, and then a left float on div #4.

Absolute positioning and negative margins is another option, not very dynamic, but it works.

The best option would be to use a bit of jQuery to solve your problem.
Check out: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Ok I will have to go with jquery then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add to the code of 4th div

```
position:relative;
top:-100px;
```

look for the class added to the 4th div

http://jsfiddle.net/eZGTm/1/

Comment: specific example. Other wise you will need jQuery and that's also very complex one.